# How do I get rid of the syntax error "duplicate class: CLASSNAME"?

Tags: java, netbeans

I thought that maybe I could rearrange my source code into different folders based on what the source code files pertained to. So I did, and I realized that it might cause some problems. I put all of the source code files back in the main folder, and now I am receiving the syntax error: `duplicate class: retailapplication.AddNewCustomerDialog`.

My question is this... How do I get rid of this issue? It does not appear as though I have more than one copy of the source code files (which isn't possible anyways, because Windows wouldn't have allowed me to do that), so I'm not sure where it is assuming that I have a duplicate.

For what it's worth, I am using the NetBeans 8.0 IDE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 02/01/2015 (9:43 PM MST) - I put ALL of my files into different folders, and I am receiving this error on three of my source code files.

Comment: Are you sure , you dont have any other class named `AddNewCustomerDialog` in your source (in the same package)

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197983 may be this link can help you

Comment: Have you changed any class name in source.

Comment: @San Krish - Yes, this is the only class by the name of `AddNewCustomerDialog`. @Vasudev Pathak - So this issue was brought to the attention of NetBeans 4 years ago, and the issue still has not been resolved?... What would be your recommendation for me, then? I don't know what I can do, because every time I run the application, I receive a message stating that there are errors, and asking me whether or not I would like to run the application. I would hate for this to cause an issue when the software is in the hands of a client...

Comment: @VasudevPathak, no, I didn't change any names of any classes, I just changed their locations, and then I reverted them back, because I was receiving a message stating that the classes were referring to the incorrect package. This error was not causing any issues at runtime, but I figured I'd resolve it anyways, by moving the class files back to the main folder of the package. That's when I was receiving the "duplicate class" error.

Comment: Is using something besides NetBeans an option? All the Java developers I know use Eclipse or IDEA.

Comment: @Ryan Shukis in same link read this post from bottom, this can help you.

Comment: @chrylis, I suppose it's an option. I've never used anything other than NetBeans, so I'm more familiar with it's layout. Also, I'm not sure that using a different IDE is going to benefit me any in this area...

Comment: @VasudevPathak, so if I build a distributable version of my application, there would be no issues. Am I correct? Because it's not going to access the cache of the IDE, right?

Comment: There's got to be a better solution...

Comment: For now, changing `C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0` to `C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0hidden` worked. Any input in regards to any negative effects this might have on this project, or any future projects?